# How do I get my Favicon to show in WordPress custom theme?

Tags: html, wordpress, twig, favicon, timber

I am trying to get a favicon to show in WordPress header and its just not working for me - what would be the problem do you think?

I am using Twig/Timber for dev.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{options.header.favicon.url | default(site.theme.link ~ '/images/favicon.ico')}}"/>`

Everything inspects just fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/themes/protool-theme/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/themes/protool-theme/images/favicon.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="author" href="http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/themes/protool-theme/humans.txt"/>
```

When I check this link it pulls up no problems at all: `http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/themes/protool-theme/images/favicon.ico` it just keeps showing the wordpress "W" favicon.

Comment: Most likely you need to delete your browser cache, reboot the browser and try again. Favicons are cached and only change when you remove them from cache.

Comment: I think cache was the main problem, but I also changed `rel="icon" ` and now all is well, so appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure Wordpress requires "icon" too.

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://protoolsite.local/wp-content/themes/protool-theme/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

It'll be easier to go to `appearance` > `customise` > `site identity` in Wordpress though.